# How to apply filter on keys in a JSON Object in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSONObject as follows,

```
{
   "field1": "value1",
   "field2": "value2",
   "field3":{
              "field4":"value4",
              "field5":"value5"
            },
   "field6":[{
              "field7":"value7",
              "field8":"value8"
            },{
              "field7":"value9",
              "field8":"value10"
            }]
}
```

and I have a list of strings like this,

```
["field1","field3.field4","field6.field7"]
```

Now, I want to apply this filter on my JSONObject and get the following output,

```
{
       "field1": "value1",
       "field3":{
                  "field4":"value4"
                },
       "field6":[{
                  "field7":"value7"
                },{
                  "field7":"value9"
                }]
    }
```

What is the simplest way to do this ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  StackOverflow works best if you post what you have done so far. Questions that look like "please write my code for me" (even if you didn't intend it that way) generally get downvoted and put on hold as off-topic.  If you show what you've tried and explain what isn't working (include stack trace and/or error messages where appropriate) you are ***much*** more likely to get help.

Comment: JsonPath is an implementation which helps in filtering out required fields.Please go through the documentation.It is very easy.Get back to us If you have doubts after implementing it.  [link](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath)

Comment: You could also try to iterate over your list of strings and try to access the specific JSON-parts. This may be a good excercise if you have not much experience with JSON until now.

Comment: we can loop over and fetch the values but i need to create a new json out of it. It get's tricky when its something like "field3.field4" or "field6.field7" because i need to know that field3 has value which is object and field6 is array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this solution using JSONParser but did not get the chance to test it 100%, It hope it will help you to play around with this problem.

```
package json.test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

public class JSonTest2 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws JsonProcessingException, IOException, ParseException {

    String jsonString="{\"field1\": \"value1\","
            + "\"field2\": \"value2\","
            + "\"field3\":{"
            + "\"field4\":\"value4\","
            + "\"field5\":\"value5\""
            + "},"
            + "\"field6\":[{"
            + "\"field7\":\"value7\","
            + "\"field8\":\"value8\""
            + "},{"
            + "\"field7\":\"value9\","
            + "\"field8\":\"value10\""
            + "}]"
            + "}";

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString);

    //System.out.println(jsonObject.containsKey("field1")); //true
    //System.out.println(jsonObject.containsKey("field3")); //true
    //System.out.println(jsonObject.containsKey("field10"));//false 
    String[] keyArray=new String[]{"field1","field3.field4","field6.field7"};
    for(String key:keyArray){
        searchKey(jsonObject,jsonObject,key.split("\\."));
        System.out.println("------------------");
    }



}

static void searchKey(JSONObject jsonObjectOrig,JSONObject jsonObjectNew, String[] key){
    if(key.length>1 &&
            jsonObjectNew.containsKey(key[0])){
        if(jsonObjectNew.get(key[0]).getClass()==JSONObject.class){
            jsonObjectNew=(JSONObject) jsonObjectNew.get(key[0]);
        }else{
            //Assume it is JsonArray
            JSONArray jsonArray=(JSONArray) jsonObjectOrig.get(key[0]);
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.size();i++){
                searchKey(jsonObjectOrig,(JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i),
                        Arrays.copyOfRange(key, 1, key.length));
            }
        }
        key=Arrays.copyOfRange(key, 1, key.length);
        searchKey(jsonObjectOrig,jsonObjectNew,key);
    }

    if(jsonObjectNew!=null &&  jsonObjectNew.containsKey(key[0])){
        System.out.println("Key  is : "+ key[0] );
        System.out.println("Key value is : "+ jsonObjectNew.get(key[0]) );
    }

}


}
```